# Static Referencing

Tags: java

Anyone know why the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method FileMenu() from the type Menu" appears?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Menu {

    public void FileMenu() {            
    }

    public void ViewMenu() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] mainbuttons = { "File", "View" };

        int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please Select An Option: ","Application Menu",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,mainbuttons, mainbuttons[2]);

        switch (choice) {
            case 0:
                FileMenu();
                break;
            case 1:
                ViewMenu();
                break;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: It happens because you are accessing the non-static `FileMenu` from the static `public static void main(String[] args){`. If  you change `FileMenu` and `ViewMenu` to static (`public static void ...`), it will work.

Comment: You need to make FileMenu() and ViewMenu() static functions since they are part of the same class as Main(). A static function can only call other static functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you cant call the non static method inside the static method (your case static `void main(String[] args)`).

to work properly make methods `FileMenu()` and  `ViewMenu()`  to static

```
public static void FileMenu() {

}

public static void ViewMenu() {


}
```

or

create Menu object and  call the FileMenu() and ViewMenu() methods .

```
Menu m = new Menu();

switch (choice) {
    case 0:
        m.FileMenu();
        break;

    case 1:
        m.ViewMenu();
        break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it obvious `FileMenu()` in your code is **not** a `static` method and down in `switch` statement you are calling it in `static` context(*i.e. without an object*).You have two options here

1. **Make FileMenu() method static** like `public static void FileMenu()` and then you can call it without any `object` of `Menu` class.
2. **Create an object of Menu class** and use it to call `FileMenu()` method. like

   `Menu obj = new Menu();`

   `obj.FileMenu();`